# react-markdown to render mix of markdown and HTML, will get warning Whitespace text nodes cannot appear as a child of <table>

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript, dangerouslysetinnerhtml, react-markdown

I need to render content that is a mix of **markdown** and regular **HTML**. The content is queried from server, which I can't decide whether there are whitespace inside table. for example the content raw data:

```
# [React](https://reactjs.org/)<br>React is a JavaScript library for building user interfaces.<br><table style=\"border: 1px solid black;\">  <tr> <td> <center>TEST TEST TES</center> </td> </tr> </table>
```

because `react-markdown` typically escapes HTML, I need to use [rehype-raw](https://unifiedjs.com/explore/package/react-markdown/#appendix-a-html-in-markdown) to render HTML properly.

For the content body above, if I just use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to render it, there will be not error except the markdown format will not be rendered.

```
<section dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.content! }}></section>
```

however if I use `react-markdown` with `rehype-raw`, although both HTML and markdown can be rendered, I get a warning in dev tool

```
        <ReactMarkdown rehypePlugins={[rehypeRaw]}>
            {props.content!}
        </ReactMarkdown>
```

> Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): Whitespace text nodes cannot appear
> as a child of . Make sure you don't have any extra whitespace
> between tags on each line of your source code.

So my questions are:

1. I know what this warning is, but why I don't get this warning when I use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` but it appears when I use `react-markdown`
2. since I can't control the content body as it's from server-side, is there any way I can prevent is warning from appearing on the dev tool?